# Probation for problematic participants?

Tags: discussion, spam

There's [someone](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/63197/hmgovermant) who has been making fairly frequent "noise" comments. Is there a mechanism for putting his comments into a review queue before they go public?

Comment: I think we can just suspend their account. They’re suspended in 3/4 of the other communities they’re in.

Comment: You can also throw links into [chat] and that will get some more attention to a post.

Comment: For context: I flagged several of this user's answers. Going off my memory, they were spam answers with some sort of possibly religious theme. I don't know that this user made comments (as opposed to answers), but I haven't been monitoring them. So, I'd classify this as worse than mere noise.

Answer (score 8):

Because of the flags you lot raised, this user is currently unable to answer.  
**Flagging posts does work and really helps.**

```
 Answer ban:yes (block not encountered)
```

---

FYI I've started the process with a mod email, laying out the issue (off-topic answer) and the next step (suspension)

I also suggested he take the non-cycling posts to facebork or twatter.

Based on the text I think user is human, not a bot, so this process lays out a history.  If it were a bot I'd delete the user without these steps.